# Does the word '铬' have other meaning besides chromium/chrome?

Tags: translation, meaning, vocabulary, meaning-in-context

那遍布的伤疤铬的她手指生疼

I don't think '铬' in this sentence means chromium, but I couldn't find other meaning except chromium in dictionary.

Is it a typo?

Comment: the sentence doesn't make sense. can you provide more context?

Comment: the complete sentence is '她紧张的颤抖着手缓缓抚上脸颊，那遍布的伤疤铬的她手指生疼，也铬的她的心生疼。'

Comment: still not getting it clearly. 伤疤（scars）can not 铬 her fingers. it's not good writing.

Comment: Haha, i think it might be a typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a typo, it should be 硌. 
If you sit on a rock, you would feel the rock 硌 your butt. 
If your hand hold a wooden stick that is not smooth, you feel 硌手.

Comment: I've check the word '硌', in mdbg it's a verb 'pressing painfully', in ichacha and ichiba it's a noun 'rock'. So '硌' could be both a noun or a verb? Also, may I know how it is read as? mdbg says 'ge' while ichiba says 'luo'....

Comment: @Fai91 Both is correct, it is 多音字. But, just dismiss the noun ('luo'), it is very rare, nobody use it as noun. .

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of chemical elements with unique Chinese characters, newly created to represent them.

Linked here is a very detailed post about the periodic table on [Language Log](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=18877), a well-reputed linguistics blog, in case you are interested in learning more about the general challenges/issues of talking chemistry in Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a typo, common mistake  in Chinese Simplified Characters usage.

I guess the right word is 烙

烙 means : use fire to heat the iron then seal to the crimial's body, is a punishment, the brand will never fade on the skin and in their mind

Other posibly is 銘，means carve

烙 and 銘 here is almost the same meaning

full sentence : 那遍佈的傷疤，烙的她手指生疼